# How to access the fields from arrays of a object in two different collections?

Tags: mongodb

This is `locations` collection data.

```
{
  _id: "1",
  location: "loc1",
  sublocations: [
    {
      _id: 2,
      sublocation: "subloc1",
    },
    {
      _id: 3,
      sublocation: "subloc2",
    }
  ]
},
{
  _id: "4",
  location: "loc2",
  sublocations: [
    {
      _id: 5,
      sublocation: "subloc1",
    },
    {
      _id: 6,
      sublocation: "subloc2",
    }
  ]
}
```

This is `products` collection data

```
{
  _id: "1",
  product: "product1",
  prices: [
    {
      _id: 2,
      sublocationid: 2,        //ObjectId of object in sublocations array 
      price: 500
    },
    {
      _id: 3,
      sublocationid: 5,        //ObjectId of object in sublocations array
      price: 200
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I need to get the `sublocation` in product schema in the prices array. Expected result is as below.

```
{
  _id: "1",
  product: "product1",
  prices: [
    {
      _id: 2,
      sublocationid: 3,
      sublocation: "subloc2", 
      price: 500
    },
    {
      _id: 3,
      sublocationid: 5,
      sublocation: "subloc1"
      price: 200
    }
  ]
}
```

To achieve it, I did it like in the following way.

- First, performing aggregation on `locations` collection - $unwind the sublocations array and store the $out in the new collection.
- Second, perform aggregation on 'products' collection - $unwind the prices, $lookup the sublocationid from the new collection and $group them.
- Third, after getting data delete the data of new collection.

Is there any other simplified way? Please let me know if there is any.

Comment: Would you mind providing the example of the result set? It would be very helpful in terms of providing the simplified query.

Comment: Another question - are sublocation ids globally unique?

Comment: I have come up with another question - is it a typo that in the prices array you have sublocation ids as strings and in the sublocations array as ints?

Comment: @cbartosiak, It is just a typo. sublocation ids are Object Ids generated automatically. I'm not assigning them explicitly. Just to give an example I gave them.

Comment: There is a simpler way but it is using upcoming 3.6 release candidate version. Let me know if you are interested and I can add it as answer.

Comment: Yeah, Please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with 3.4 version, you can try this query:

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: {
            "path": "$prices"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            "from": "locations",
            "localField": "prices.sublocationid",
            "foreignField": "sublocations._id",
            "as": "locations"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            "path": "$locations"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            "path": "$locations.sublocations"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "keep": {
                "$eq": [
                    "$prices.sublocationid",
                    "$locations.sublocations._id"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "keep": true
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "price": {
                "_id": "$prices._id",
                "sublocationid": "$prices.sublocationid",
                "sublocation": "$locations.sublocations.sublocation",
                "price": "$prices.price"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "product": { "$first": "$product" },
            "prices": { "$addToSet": "$price" }
        }
    }
]);
```

It's not as nice as 3.6 version though, because of a higher memory consumption.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation query in 3.6 version.

Since both local field and foreign field are array you have to `$unwind` both to do equality comparison.

For this you will have to use new [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-syntax-let-pipeline) syntax.

`$match` with `$expr` provides comparsion between document fields to look up the location's sublocation document for each product's sublocation id.

`$project` to project the matching sublocation doc.

`$addFields` with `$arrayElemAt` to convert the looked up sublocation array into a document.

`$group` to push all prices with matching sublocation's document for each product.

```
db.products.aggregate[
  {
    "$unwind": "$prices"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "locations",
      "let": {
        "prices": "$prices"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$unwind": "$sublocations"
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": [
              "$$prices.sublocationid",
              "$sublocations._id"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "sublocations": 1,
            "_id": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "prices.sublocations"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "prices.sublocations": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$prices.sublocations",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "product": {
        "$first": "$product"
      },
      "prices": {
        "$push": "$prices"
      }
    }
  }
])
```